# Incorrect value from SQL SUM of two columns in different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

This MS Access SQL Query does not return the correct value. I am attempting to sum the commission from TransactionBuy and TransactionSell tables between two dates input on a form. However, the result is incorrect.

```
SELECT (Sum([TransactionBuy].[Commission])+Sum([TransactionSell].[Commission])) AS Total
FROM TransactionBuy, TransactionSell
WHERE (TransactionBuy.DateTime Between Forms![AT - frmCommission]![txtStart]
And  Forms![AT - frmCommission]![txtEnd]) 
AND (TransactionSell.DateTime Between Forms! [AT - frmCommission]![txtStart] 
And  Forms![AT - frmCommission]![txtEnd]);
```

Comment: Can you add some (wrong) example calculations? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try aggregating before doing the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT ts.Commission + tb..[Commission] AS Total
FROM (SELECT Sum([TransactionBuy].[Commission]) as commission
      FROM TransactionBuy
      WHERE TransactionBuy.DateTime Between Forms![AT - frmCommission]![txtStart] And  Forms![AT - frmCommission]![txtEnd]
     ) as tb,
     (SELECT Sum([TransactionSell].[Commission]) as commission
      FROM TransactionSell
      WHERE TransactionSell.DateTime Between Forms! [AT - frmCommission]![txtStart] And  Forms![AT - frmCommission]![txtEnd]
    ) ts;
```

Answer (score 0):

This make more sense.  Is it accepted by Access?

```
SELECT SUM(Commission) as Total
FROM (
SELECT [TransactionBuy].[Commission])
FROM TransactionBuy, 
WHERE (TransactionBuy.DateTime Between Forms![AT - frmCommission]![txtStart]
And  Forms![AT - frmCommission]![txtEnd]) 

UNION ALL

SELECT [TransactionSell].[Commission]
FROM TransactionSell
WHERE (TransactionSell.DateTime Between Forms! [AT - frmCommission]![txtStart] 
And  Forms![AT - frmCommission]![txtEnd])
)
```